# Office 365 Keeps prompting for password and forgetting outlook passwords

Tags: windows, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have an education license for MS Office 365 that I can use on 5 devices. On three devices it works fine. Installed on PC (Win 10) at home and it works fine for an hour maybe more, after which word/excel/etc displays the warning triangle with the message:

```
"Account Error. Sorry, we can't get to your account right now. To fix this, please sign in again."
```

After which my passwords in outlook have been forgotten.

I've reinstalled Office, I've run SFC and DISM with no errors, I've run full virus check and malwarebytes scans and nothing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I keep office signed in? Thanks

Notes:

The problem persists after signing in/out of word/excel and after reinstalling

Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21296) 64 bit - just updated to 21378

Word version 2002 (build 12527.21416)

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter the same issue if you tried to sign out/in your account in the Word/Excel and other office applications?

> **I've reinstalled Office, I've run SFC and DISM with no errors, I've run full virus check and malwarebytes scans and nothing.**

After reinstalling Office, did the issue happen again?

What's the build version of your Office 365? I think you could try to update office to the latest version and see if there is any difference.

Comment: I have updated my post above with more details.

Comment: @jeffporter 

1. Please navigate to the website(**Devices**: https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list) to see if the number of devices which use this account to sign in office application has excuted the limit(5).
2. Besides, check if certain service disconnected(Word -> File -> Office Account -> Connected Services)
3. Are the left clients in your organization or external? Did your domain administrator configure a group policy to block the sign-in function of office 365 on external clients?